# After filtering array Slice method is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am try to build a news portal app using Next JS, Redux, mongoose, and Express.

## My Problems is:

When I am try to filter specific item from array it's working perfectly. But, When I am trying to show specific number of items like 5 or 3 item using slice() method is not working. It show every items in filtered.

[image: I slice 4 items but here you can see show all item in this category]

## Edit: My API

```
// http://localhost:5000/api/news

const news = [
  {
    "_id": "62381db6e2a1e30962ea8116",
    "title": "TEST",
    "excerpt": "test excerpt",
    "description": "test descriptions",
    "thumb": "/uploads\\image-1647844783215.jpg",
    "categories": [
      {
        "_id": "6230e332a9aef46d0ac16b96",
        "name": "MongoDB",
        "slug": "mongodb",
        "createdAt": "2022-03-15T19:04:18.174Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-03-15T19:04:18.174Z",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "user": {
      "_id": "6230f8f33d17c88cf66befaa",
      "name": "test",
      "email": "inadafo.mdborhan@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2a$10$PKzJBVWxg9bnmNUgJL.qzOWfQxuZToJe7NaKNBQeLUwEeMRuk7Jb2",
      "image": "/uploads\\image-1647376625358.jpg",
      "isAdmin": true,
      "posts": [
        
      ],
      "createdAt": "2022-03-15T20:37:07.298Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-03-21T06:51:41.420Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "news": [
        "62381db6e2a1e30962ea8116",
        "6238207de2a1e30962ea812e"
      ]
    },
    "createdAt": "2022-03-21T06:39:51.594Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-03-21T06:39:51.594Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

## Here is my code:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const PF = 'http://localhost:5000'
const tempImg = 'https://socialistmodernism.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/placeholder-image.png?w=640'

function SubLeadNews({news}) {

  return (
    <>
      {/* <!-- items --> */}
      {
        news?.map((item) => (

          item.categories.filter((category) => category.slug === "mongodb").slice(0, 4).map((news) => (
              <div class="sub-lead-news-item">
                <div>
                  <div class="sub-lead-news-thumb">
                    <Link href="/single">
                      <a>
                          <img src={`${PF}${item.thumb}`} alt={item.title} />
                      </a>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-lead-news-content">
                    <Link href={`/${item._id}`}>
                      <a>
                        <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                      </a>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
          ))

        ))
      }

    </>
  )
}

export default SubLeadNews
```

Now I want show filtered 4 number of item in array.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the first 'N' number of elements in arr then you can use this

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

arr.slice(0,N).map((ele => console.log(ele)))

//Result 
1
2
3
4
```